# Example of an uncountable metric space where every point is isolated

Tags: metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

I was trying to come up with an example of an uncountable metric space all of whose points are isolated. I've had difficulty thinking of one, has anyone got any nice examples?

Just in case:

**Definition:** a point $x \in M $ is *not* isolated if for everly $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $y \in M$ such that $0< d(x,y) < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Take any uncountable set and give it the [discrete metric](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteMetric.html).

Comment: It's worth pointing out how $\mathbb R ^n$ contains no such subspace.

Comment: Yes I can believe that, I was looking for some subset of Euclidean space but came up with nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Real numbers with the discrete metric. I.e. $d(x,y) = 1$ if $x \neq y$.

Comment: of course! Thanks :)

Comment: I was playing around too much with the set $M$ rather than what metric we attached.